# Was Stack Overflow the first website in Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion

Was Stack Overflow the first website created in the Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) had all existed for years before The Stack Exchange Network was created.  There was no one "first" site in the network.

Stack Overflow could be considered "first" in that it *was* the first of the original three mentioned above, but there was no formal Stack Exchange Network at the point Stack Overflow was created.

Comment: Well, if you exclude the trilogy, the first one was WebApps and the second Gaming :)

Comment: @JuanManuel There's Stack Apps, which according to [this](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest), is older than Webapps.

Answer (score 11):

If you go to [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest) and sort by Oldest you can see what order the sites were launched.  Stack Overflow is the oldest site in the network, but it existed before SE, making the wording of your question slightly ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

If you exclude the Trilogy sites and include SE 1.0 sites, I'm going to guess that its

http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com

Since its [first question](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/1/) is is dated 9/4/2009 which predates the other SE 1.0 sites non-migrated questions that I could find. That and the fact that its the first logical site to be on SE 1.0

Comment: Probably not what the OP meant, but nice bit of history!

Comment: @PopularDemand yeah its just too bad the old list of S.E. 1.0 sites is gone [but you knew that already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28384/sites-similar-to-stackoverflow#comment199305_28389) although I did manage to dig up an [old article](http://www.readwriteweb.com/start/2009/10/stackoverflow-shares-its-mojo.php) (check out the SE Logo), and [the podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/podcast-70/) announcing the SE beta

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **Stack Overflow** is **the oldest** one.

And here is a full list, sorted by age, oldest first >>

```
 Stack Overflow
 Server Fault
 Super User
 Meta Stack Overflow
 Web Applications
 Gaming
 Webmasters
 Cooking
 Game Development
 Photography
 Statistical Analysis
 Mathematics
 Home Improvement
 GIS
 TeX - LaTeX
 Ask Ubuntu
 Personal Finance and Money
 English Language and Usage
 Stack Apps
 User Experience
 Unix and Linux
 WordPress
 Theoretical Computer Science
 Apple
 Role-playing Games
 Bicycles
 Programmers
 Electrical Engineering
 Android Enthusiasts
 OnStartups
 Board and Card Games
 Physics
 Homebrewing
 IT Security
 Writers
 Audio-Video Production
 Graphic Design
 Database Administrators
 Science Fiction and Fantasy
 Code Review
 Code Golf
 Quantitative Finance
 Project Management
 Skeptics
 Fitness and Nutrition
 Drupal Answers
 Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair
 Parenting
 SharePoint
 Musical Practice and Performance
 Software Quality Assurance and Testing
 Jewish Life and Learning
 German Language and Usage
 Japanese Language and Usage
 Astronomy
 Philosophy
 Gardening and Landscaping
 Travel
 Personal Productivity
 Cryptography
 Literature
 Signal Processing
 French Language and Usage
 Christianity
 Bitcoin
 Linguistics
 Theoretical Physics
 Biblical Hermeneutics
 History
 Economics
 Healthcare IT
 LEGO® Answers
 Firearms
 Spanish Language and Usage
 Computational Science
 Movies and TV
 Chinese Language and Usage
 Biology
 Poker
 Mathematica
 Cognitive Sciences
 The Great Outdoors
 SmugMug
 Martial Arts
 Sports
 Academia
 Computer Science
```